# How can I export a pruned phylogenetic tree in nexus format in R?

Tags: r, phylogenetics, file-formats

I have a phylogenetic tree with a lot of different populations and I wanted to removes most of them and apply new names to the labels. I wrote this code:

```r
library(ape)
library(phylotools)
tree<- read.tree("Consensus_COMBINED_Cod3genesRatesC_trees.trees")

tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip = c("CeuMist2","CeuMist1","Ceu_PAN_2","Ceu_PAN_1","Ceu_PAN_3","Ceu_PAN_4"))
tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip= c("CcNav1","CcNav2","Cc_Mal_1","Cc_KalR2_2","CcRod1","CcRod2","CcRod3","CcRod4","CcHr1"))
tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip= c("CeST6_4","CeST6_5","CeAA7_1","CeST6_3","CeST6_2"))
tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip= c("Cg_MelR3_1","Cg_MelR6_2","Cg_MelR7_2","Cg_MelR6_1","Cg_MelR7_3","Cg_MelR5_1","Cg_MelR4_2","Cg_MelR1_1","Cg_MelR2_1","Cg_MelR4_1","Cg_MelR7_4","Cg_MelR5_2"))
tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip= c("ChTM5_1","ChTM4_3","ChTM4_1","Ch_MEN_5","Ch_MEN_13","Ch_MEN_8","Ch_LEV_3","Ch_LEV_5","Ch_LEV_4","Ch_MEN_6","Ch_MEN_10","Ch_LEV_2","Ch_MEN_4","Ch_MEN_14","Ch_LEV_1","Ch_MEN_11","Ch_MEN_3","Ch_MEN_9"))
tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip= c("Ci_MSP_2","Ci_MSP_1","Ci_DIA_1","Ci_DIA_2","CiPLAN1","CiPLAN3","CiPLAN2","Ci_MEN_1","Ci_MEN_2","Ci_MEN_12"))
tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip= c("CpGravR3","CpGravR4","CpGio_2","CpGravR5_2","CpGravR2","CpGravR7","CpGio_1","CpGio_3","CpGravR1","CpGravR6_2","CpGravR5_1","CpThe_1","CpSka_1"))
tree<- drop.tip(tree, tip= c("Cn_IG_2","Cn_IG_3","Cn_IG_1","LevantinaFC4779","Assyriella_naegelei"))

newlabels<- c("C. eucineta", "C. codringtonii", "C. elisabethae","C. gittenbergeri", "C. helenae", "C. intusplicata", "C. parnassia")
tree$tip.label<- newlabels

write.nexus(tree, "CodTree.trees")
```

When I use the `write.nexus` command I get the following error:

```r
Error in y$tip.label : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How can I circumvent this error and export the tree in nexus format?

I will also provide the tree here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYmzW9htwaclC_yYs3fQom-Z3zbjk8wH/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hi @Nickmofoe I'll look at this in detail, but will not be until the end of the week (really busy week).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after digging I found the solution. What worked for me was adding the `file =`  in the `write.nexus` command. The final line should be
`write.nexus(tree, file =  "Cod.trees")`

Comment: Ahhh! Right of course! Many thanks for posting back. Could you very kindly mark you post as "accepted". Admittedly, you don't any bonus rep, but it helps site statistics and it is definitely the solution. I completely missed the `file =`.